# npm install - don't authenticate

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install npm package using
`npm install {pacakge_name}`

When using the npm install, npm will get my npm auth token from .npmrc.
I want to install the package anonymously, or without authentication (for my own reasons) but I was unable to find a way to do so.

I have tried using env variables, but npm will first check if the npmrc is defined and will use it if so.

Is there a way (configuration or some flag I could use) that will allow me to install package without passing my npm auth token (without deleting the npmrc file)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is built in support for that. You can achieve better isolation by running npm in a docker container.

```sh
docker run -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:lts npm install {package_name}
```

Or if you just care about swapping out your npmrc just write a small shell function to rename the file before the command and replace it after the command.